# preg_replace() str_replace() apostrophe nightmare! - Drupal menu image replace

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, preg-replace

Can anyone help me decode why this doesnt work?

```
$cssid = preg_replace("/'/", "", $cssid);
```

Trying to strip the single quote marks from some html...

Thanks!
H

EDIT
This is the full function - it's designed to rebuild the Drupal menu using images, and it applies CSS classes to each item, allowing you to select the image you want. Stripping out spaces and apostrophes needs to be done or the CSS selector fails.

The title of the menu item causing all this problem is:

```
What's new
```

Pretty innocuous you'd think. (Except for that single ')

```
function primary_links_add_icons() {
  $links = menu_primary_links();
  $level_tmp = explode('-', key($links));
  $level = $level_tmp[0];
  $output = "<ul class=\"links-$level\">\n";   
  if ($links) {
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        $link = l($link['title'], $link['href'], $link['attributes'], $link['query'], $link['fragment']);
        $cssid = str_replace(' ', '_', strip_tags($link));
        $cssid = str_replace('\'', '', $cssid);
        /*$link = preg_replace('#(<a.*?>).*?(</a>)#', '$1$2', $link);*/
        $output .= '<li id="'.$cssid.'">' . $link .'</li>';
    };
    $output .= '</ul>';
  }
  return $output;
}
```

EDIT the saga continues...

I notice that I get the following error in PHPMYADMIN:

> The mbstring PHP extension was not
>   found and you seem to be using a
>   multibyte charset. Without the
>   mbstring extension phpMyAdmin is
>   unable to split strings correctly and
>   it may result in unexpected results.

I wonder whether this has something to do with it?

In any case the the SQL code is:

```
('primary-links', 951, 0, 'http://www.google.com', '', 'What''s New',
```

And this displays in FireBug once it's been rendered as:

```
<li id="What's_New">
```

I've created a menu item called "What@s New" and the str_replace() will work on that just fine, so it's ALL about this goddam apostrophe. I think I agree, the expression works, but it has to be an encoding problem. It really is a proper, common, apostrophe and not one of the variants, but for some reason PHP is absolutely unable to recognise it as such.

EDIT oh god oh god - it's Drupal again...
It appears that the function l() which formats all the links is completely impervious to having it's output rewritten?! Whatever the case, this code works...

```
function primary_links_add_icons() {
  $links = menu_primary_links();
  $level_tmp = explode('-', key($links));
  $level = $level_tmp[0];
  $output = "<ul class=\"links-$level\">\n";   
  if ($links) {
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        $link['title'] = str_replace('\'', '', $link['title']);
        $link = l($link['title'], $link['href'], $link['attributes'], $link['query'], $link['fragment']);
        $cssid = str_replace(' ', '_', strip_tags($link));      
        /*$link = preg_replace('#(<a.*?>).*?(</a>)#', '$1$2', $link);*/
        $output .= '<li id="'.$cssid.'">' . $link .'</li>';
    };
    $output .= '</ul>';
  }
  return $output;
}
```

2 hours later and I can carry on theming this site...

Thank you so much for all your suggestions, I'm going to point the drupal snippet authors at this post so hopefully other people will benefit from it too.

Comment: So `$link` contains `What's new`, right? Are you sure it’s an `'` (U+0027) and not something similar looking like `\`` (U+0060), `´` (U+00B4), `‘` (U+2018), `’` (U+2019) or `‛` (U+201B)?

Comment: yeah, i've typed and retyped it. I might go into the database and see if the character encoding is messing this up somehow though.

Comment: Like Gumbo says, are you sure it is a ' ... you should test your functions not with live data (very error prone!) but with self made data first; which you know will work. If that works, fire it on your live data.. see what happens.

Comment: That code works for me... `$cssid` gets a value `Whats_new`.

Comment: Also, try setting your magic_quotes off in php.ini. Not sure if it helps though, lol.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this turns out to be a no-brainer in the end.

Comment: I'm betting some sort of encoding problem. The character will turn out not to be an apostrophe -- *agh, I have to use cut&paste to get that word correct every single time I use it! :)*

Comment: you could try to replace something different (say, all 't'-occurrences) see if the function works as it should. then, you are sure the ' you are looking for, isn't a ' at all!

Comment: Edit my post again - this is getting weirder. It has to be server side problem afaik

Comment: Hmmm … Try `"'"` or `chr(39)` instead of `'\''`.

Comment: Nope :(  I'm installing this whole setup on another server running Apache - I'll see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS image replacement** is a much more commonly chosen way for menu item replacing:

First install: [Menu Attributes module](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) to be able to assing css id's for every menu item. (these attributes can be set from the menu item edit page on admin panel)

Then use css image replacement. [Here](http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/) is a good tutorial for this.

And this is the method i use for my sites:

```
    #primary-tv
{
    display: block;
    width: 90px;
    height: 0px;
    padding-top: 41px;
    background: url(images/nghtv.png);
}
```

This is an example for replacement with an image of 90 x 41px

And for the apostrophe replacement:

```
$cssid = preg_replace("&#039;","",htmlspecialchars($cssid, ENT_QUOTES));
```

Comment: You know, I WISH Drupal.org would have stuff like this just laid out. It's one of the best, yet conversely WORST documented CMS's i've used :( Thanks for the tip though, that looks great!

Comment: Documentation is a hard work and drupal.org has too many content so it's harder to document everything. I also heard some work on Lullabot podcast about documentation problem. I'm sure that we can't find solution to our every problems, but new Drupal Search which is powered by Apache Solr and the Issue system helps. ( also I mostly use "google search" with site:drupal.org parameter for my drupal queries :) )

Comment: yeah I know what you mean. But surely there's got to be a "install these modules to make a nice CMS" article out there :P

Answer (score 2):

escape the single quote.

Comment: still no... I've tried damn near every combination I can think of. This is driving me mad!

Comment: $cssid = str_replace('\'', '', $cssid); 
should definitely work.. unless there's something different in your php.ini?

Comment: Still no :(  I'm perfectly prepared to believe it's the PHP ini - this is being developed on a IIS system run by FastHosts.com and they are f*cking terrible. Hosting aside, any other ideas?

Comment: I just confirmed that it works when using single quotes only.

Comment: I used this code; $string = "<body onload='test'>";
$string = str_replace('\'',"-",$string);

Comment: I just tried this in my page body and it works. So it's something out there in the function which is mucking this up: $string = "<p>this is'a test' example</p>"; $string = str_replace('\'',"-",$string); echo $string;

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. But why don’t you use [`str_replace`](http://docs.php.net/str_replace) as you’re replacing a fixed string?

```
$cssid = str_replace("'", "", $cssid);
```

Comment: mainly because that doesnt work either :) It's been bugging the hell out of me for half an hour and stopping me from finishing my work :x

Comment: You sir are a genius. Why didn't I think of that. If I had, I might have come and posted on... oh wait.

Answer (score 1):

If `str_replace("'","")` doesn't work, are you sure the characters you want to remove are indeed normal apostrophes (') instead of weird alternatives (’), or some weird accent marks (´`˙ ̛̉῾᾿) or single quotes (‘’) or whatnot?

Or maybe the value of `$cssid` gets replaced back to original by some other bug?

Maybe you're looking at the wrong output for results?

Or by a far chance, are you accidentally running a different copy of the code than the one you are editing - btw, that's really annoying when it happens! :)

Comment: haha yeah that occurred to me too - as far as I'm able to see it is indeed a plain old apostrophe and none of the alternatives. cssid is also a completely made up variable, so it's not getting replaced anywhere. And yeah, this code is getting published correctly :D

Comment: To be sure it's the correct character, you could try `file_put_contents('debug.txt',$cssid)` and copy the character from the debug.txt to your code, see if that works...

Comment: Or, ehm, easier check would be to force `$cssid = "What's new"` before the replace, and check if that works... (It'll affect every list item of course, but for debug it shoudln't matter.)

Answer (score 1):

Given that it is HTML have you considered that it may be represented as &#39 rather than '?